# Issues when inputting code into PyCharm IDE for Python?

Tags: ide, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I'm experiencing some weird issues with PyCharm. When typing on highlighted text I get the error beeping noise from Windows 10 sounds. <kbd>Ctrl + A</kbd> also has suddenly seemed to stop working?

When highlighting text and hitting `DEL` it just plays the error sound again and highlights the above line?

Anybody know a solution to this?

Comment: Does this happen only in PyCharm or in any other Windows programs as well?

Comment: 1) Any custom plugins? Disable all of them and restart IDE. 2) What keymap is used 3) Have you tried restarting whole PC? 4) As last resort you may try backing up and deleting IDE wide settings and start from scratch.